# requests повторить post запрос

Tags: python, post, requests

Просмотрел в браузере какие запросы отправляются к api, пост запрос имеет такие параметры:

```
{"currency":"rub","filter":{"eggs":false,"pets":true},"sort":{"popularity":"desc"},"page":2}
```

как записать ключ: значение мне понятно, а как быть с таким форматом `"filter":{"eggs":false,"pets":true}`

я пытаюсь отправить пост запрос таким вот образом

```
payload = {'currency': 'rub', 'filter': ["eggs":"false","pets":"true"],'sort': ["popularity":"desc"], "page":"2" }  
r = requests.post('https://сайт/', data = payload)
```

но очевидно, что запись `payload` не правильная

Comment: Сдаётся мне, что браузер отправляет всё это в JSON-формате. Тогда и Вам стоит делать так же.

Comment: то есть нужно конвертировать строку в джисон и  написать условно так `data = json` ?

Comment: @test, `json=payload`

Comment: при этом, булевые и численные значения не нужно записывать как строку. То есть, не `"false"`, а `false`, и не `"2"`, a `2`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
import json


payload = {'currency': 'rub', 'filter': 
["eggs":"false","pets":"true"],'sort': ["popularity":"desc"], "page":"2" }  
r = requests.post('https://сайт/', data=json.dumps(payload))
```